# How to add "-lm" (LDFLAGS) correctly to this Makefile?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

I have this perfectly working Makefile but I don't know how to add the "-lm" parameter. I found a lot on stackoverflow but those example Makefiles look completely different to mine.

How should I add "-lm" to this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g -pthread -std=gnu99
SRCS =  main.c client.c
DEPS = client.h

EXEC = peer

OBJS= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(EXEC)
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@  $^

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $<

run: peer
    ./peer
clean:
    rm $(OBJS)
    rm peer
```

Comment: Try `LDLIBS = -lm`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Comment: Delete most of your makefile and let make use implicit rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries dependencies are resolved when you are linking your object files together into an executable. You're doing that in this step:

```
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@  $^
```

You would typically make your command line look something like:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@  $^ $(LIBS)
```

I've replaced `$(CFLAGS)` here with `$(LDFLAGS)` because you typically want a different set of flags for linking your code than you do for compiling your code.

To link in the math library, you would then add the following at the top of your `Makefile`:

```
LIBS = -lm -lpthread
```

Giving you:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g -pthread -std=gnu99
LIBS = -lm -lpthread
SRCS =  main.c client.c
DEPS = client.h

EXEC = peer

OBJS= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(EXEC)
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
  $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

run: peer
  ./peer

clean:
  rm $(OBJS)
  rm peer
```

The linking step would look like:

```
gcc  -o peer  main.o client.o -lm -lpthread
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd also suggest replacing `gcc` with `$(CC)`. As it stands, the only thing that `$(CC)` controls is the link step, which is confusing.

Comment: +1 to using `$(CC)` everywhere rather than mixing up sometimes using a var and sometimes using a literal string.

Comment: Sorry for that stupid question again but it gives me `"Makefile:13: *** missing separator.  Stop."`
for the line `"$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@  $^"`

What parameter should LDFLAGS have?

Comment: @Benny have you fixed up spaces back to tabs where appropriate (at the beginning of the command)?

Comment: Yeah, the Markdown here doesn't preserve tabs.  Indentation in a `Makefile` (e.g., for the commands to build a target) must use tabs.

Comment: That was the error. But it still does not work. :(

`undefined reference to pthread_create`

`undefined reference to pow'`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
`Makefile:13: recipe for target 'peer' failed`

Comment: I believe that `$(LIBS)` should be placed at the _end_ of the command.

Comment: @Benny: The `undefined reference to pow` is because I had placed `$(LIBS)` at the wrong point in the command.  The `undefined reference to pthread_create` suggests that you also need `-lpthread`.